# Are p‐xylylene and fulvene aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, aromaticity

> Are the following structures aromatic?
>
> [image: p‐xylylene and fulvene]

I have not seen this type of question anywhere so I do not know the answer.
This is just a problem that has been roaming around in my head that I may have seen somewhere.

My approach: since aromaticity leads to stability the carbon-carbon bond in both structure should be polar leading to aromaticity like this:

[image: p‐xylylene and fulvene — ionic form]

But this is just a thought and I do not know if it is right.
Is any of the two structures aromatic?

Comment: Related: [How to explain (non-/anti-) aromaticity in fulvene with the help of resonance structures?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/82175/7951)

Comment: First off, the polarized form drawn for fulvene is wrong.  To make this contribution aromatic, draw a positive charge on the pendant carbon and a negative charge on the ring.

Answer (score -2):

To decide if a molecule is aromatic or not you must know some rules-

1. The Molecule Must Be Cyclic and the system should be conjugated.
2. The molecule must follow Huckle's rule i.e. it should have (4n+2) Pi Electrons participating in resonance.

   3.The molecule must be planar.

---

For details see-https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_15%3A_Benzene_and_Aromaticity/15.03_Aromaticity_and_the_Huckel_4n___2_Rule

---

Now if you try to draw the resonance structure for your 1st molecule then you will see that 4 electrons are participating in resonance at a time. **So the system is not fully conjugated.** It will be a cross conjugated system.So both the structures you have mentioned are **non aromatic**.

---

Stability is a result of aromaticity. You can not comment that if a compound is stable then it is due to aromaticity.

---

Here is an image showing resonance in para xylylene.

[image: Resonance in para xylylene]

---

---

It can be seen from the resonating structures that some of the resonance structures are not aromatic making the molecule non-aromatic in total.

Any recommendations on making the image better are welcomed.

Comment: I still do not understand why the overall molecule in 1st problem is not conjugated. Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: I have edited the answer if its still unclear do let me know.

Comment: It is clear now but i think the 3rd structure should be the most contributing structure. Since that structure is highly contributing, shouldn't the molecule exhibit its properties?

Comment: Molecule will exhibit the properties of the resonance hybrid and not of any one of its contributing structures.

Comment: @Groverkss This will give you the most appropriate idea on it https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/is-the-aromaticity-broken-in-some-resonance-structures-of-para-nitro-aminobenzen