# Which is most stable resonance structure of 4-nitrophenoxide ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

[image]According to my coaching module the first structure is more stable. Why is this so? I feel both must be approximately equally stable since negative charge is on oxygen in both cases. Would someone please give me a hint?

Comment: There is no such thing as a most stable resonance structure. If anyone tells you otherwise, don't listen, it's wrong. See also: [What is resonance, and are resonance structures real?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51632/4945)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I mean the major contributor to the final hybrid structure, why exactly is the first one the major one?

Comment: Consider aromaticity

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN would you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You were quite correct in saying that the negative charge is present on oxygen in both the cases, so the idea of comparing the negative charge being present on the most electronegative atom goes out of the window. All the octets are complete here, and there is no scope for minimizing charge separation. Now, I don't know whether you have studied aromaticity yet, but a quick glance through the Wikipedia page on the same will tell you that aromatic systems are tremendously stable. Hence, 1st option is the major contributor

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN thank you! Yes, I was actually still in the process of studying aromaticity, thanks!