# Resonance structures and mechanism

Tags: resonance

I wrote the following resonance structures and our teacher wants us to write the curved arrows showing the mechanism as well... I was wondering if it's okay to show in which direction the mechanism arrows are meant - I hope the question makes sense...

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. Resonance has very little to do with a mechanism except that both might use the same arrows to indicate the electron flow. What you have drawn in both examples is one step of a mechanism to produce a resonance stabilized intermediate.

Comment: Related to what Zhe has said: [What is resonance, and are resonance structures real?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51632/4945) The depictions are fine, as long as you keep in mind that none of the structures within the brackets actually exist, therefore the arrows used are a mere derivation tool.

Comment: @Zhe - thank you both for your comments - it helped me and from now on I will distinguish between electron flow and mechanism :)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン thank you very much as well :)